# How do I save particular frames of video into folders using python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, motion-detection

I have got a code that does motion detection. It takes video as an input and then when an object comes to the scene, background changes and code publishes "object is seen" as text on that detected frame.

My question is that how do I save frames "when objects are seen" into folders( both for colorful and gray images)? I understand that I can write that frames using "  cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, resizedFrame)" but unfortunately it does not work.

How do I save those detected frames to "colorful" and "gray" folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the image first by `cv2.imread()` and then  `cv2.imwrite()`
here is a small example

```py
import
cv2
 
# read image as grey scale
grey_img=cv2.imread('/home/img/python.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
 # save image
status=cv2.imwrite('/home/img/python_grey.png',grey_img)
 print("Image written to file-system : ",status)
```

If you're don't have the folder path then use this
`status=cv2.imwrite('python_grey.png',grey_img)`
it will save the photo in default folder in which you save your `.py` file

if you want to save different images here is the code

```py
import cv2
import time

# for number of images you need different names so set name automatically
name=str(time.time())+str(.png))
 # read image as grey scale
grey_img=cv2.imread('/home/img/python.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
 # save image
status=cv2.imwrite('%s'%name,grey_img)
 print("Image written to file-system : ",status)
```

Comment: I know these things, my question is about this particular problem when there is no folder to read from. How do I save those particular frames during the processing?

Comment: You can simple ignore the folder path and just write ```cv2.imwritr('photo.jpg',img)```

Comment: ok, thanks, can you please edit your answer and make it for saving a loop of images? I am going to choose your answer.

Comment: Can you want to save different images

Comment: yes, because I am reading these frames from a video. Thanks